# Passing Filepath to second activity in andriod studio

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android programming and having a problem in passing a filepath from my main activity to second activity.

Here is my code in Main activity to pass two variables walletDir(contains path) and password.

```
private File walletDir;
private final String password = "pass";
Intent intent= new Intent(Create_Wallet.this,Wallet_Address.class);
            intent.putExtra("EXTRA_WALLET_DIR", walletDir);
            intent.putExtra("EXTRA_PASSWORD", password);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Here is my code for second activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String walletDir = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_WALLET_DIR");
    String password = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_PASSWORD");
```

Now password is being passed but not walletDir its null and the error i am getting is:

```
W/Bundle: Key EXTRA_WALLET_DIR expected String but value was a java.io.File.  The default value <null> was returned.
```

Comment: `walletDir(contains path)` That tells us noting. Just declare that variable in your code and assign it a value. We wanna see type and all. The same for all variables. If you look at the errror message you should realise that you mess around with types of variables.

Comment: I have updated it and yes i know the reason is that i am putting file value(walletDir) in String on second activity. I am having issues with how i do it.Thanks

Comment: You have not assigned a value to walletDir.

Comment: Well you put an instance of the File class in. Add you try to retrieve an instance of the String class. That is what you do wrong. The error message just tells you that.

Comment: I just did not put that in here but i have assigned a value and made sure by System.out.println

Comment: You should post code here that we can copy and paste to try it out when we want to try it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
private File walletDir;
```

`walletDir` is an instance of `File`.

```java
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_WALLET_DIR", walletDir);
```

This puts an instance of `File` into your `Intent` as an extra. This works because `File` implements the `Serializable` interface, and there is a `putExtra()` method that takes a `Serializable`.

```
String walletDir = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_WALLET_DIR");
```

The extra is not a `String`. Yet, you call `getStringExtra()` to read it. This is not going to work, because a `File` is not a `String`.

Change that line to:

```
File walletDir = (File)intent.getSerializableExtra("EXTRA_WALLET_DIR");
```

(it is possible that you do not need the cast — it has been quite some time since I did this in Java)

You might also consider whether you really should be using two activities here. Android is moving **very strongly** towards having fewer activities, with fragments or composables representing individual screens displayed by those activities.